# How do I check whether a date input includes days in Python?

Tags: python, parsing, python-dateutil

I'm working on a block of Python code that is meant to test inputs to determine whether they're numeric, timestamps, free text, etc. To detect dates, it uses the dateutil parser, then checks if the parse succeeded or an exception was thrown.

However, the dateutil parser is too forgiving and will turn all manner of values into date objects, such as time ranges, eg "12:00-16:00", being converted into timestamps on the current day, eg "2023-08-22T12:00-16:00" (which isn't even a valid timezone offset).

We'd like to only treat inputs as dates if they actually have a day-month-year component, not if they're just hours and minutes - but we still want to accept various date formats, yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss or dd/MM/yyyy or whatever the input uses. Is there another library better suited to this, or some way to make dateutil stricter?

Comment: Looking through the source code, there doesn't seem to be any way to control this. But it is open source, so you can go the route of forking it if you want, or monkey-patching, which is relatively trivial in Python, although you then take on the  responsibility of maintaining that, because you will have to use internal implementation details that could break. At the very least, you'll want to add tests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about the python's re module. You can check string with regular expression to determine whether the string is valid date/datetime data and then you can use dateutil module.

for example, following snippets will determine whether the input string has the proper date pattern.

```
import re

def check_date(text)
   date_regex = re.compile(r"(/d{4}-/d{2}-/d{2}") # for "yyyy-mm-dd" pattern
   if re.search(data_regx, text):
      return True
   else:
      return False
```

Now, depending on the function's return you can use dateutil or datetime module to parse the string into date/datetime object.

Comment: That regex is actually too strict, since we want to recognise all sorts of different date formats so long as they have day, month, and year in some fashion, but yeah, looks like we might end up going with a regex of some sort.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/dateutil/dateutil/blob/master/src/dateutil/parser/_parser.py) it doesn't look like there is any way to make the parser stricter.

But, it is open source. So we can understand what is going on. The main magic happens in the [`parser._parse`](https://github.com/dateutil/dateutil/blob/296d419fe6bf3b22897f8f210735ac9c4e1cb796/src/dateutil/parser/_parser.py#L666) method. Basically, a bunch of logic is used to resolve a date. It eventually always returns a tuple:

```
    except (IndexError, ValueError):
        return None, None

    if not info.validate(res):
        return None, None

    if fuzzy_with_tokens:
        skipped_tokens = self._recombine_skipped(l, skipped_idxs)
        return res, tuple(skipped_tokens)
    else:
        return res, None
```

Then in [parser.parse](https://github.com/dateutil/dateutil/blob/296d419fe6bf3b22897f8f210735ac9c4e1cb796/src/dateutil/parser/_parser.py#L572) we see that the `default` values are filled in to this result (and appropriate errors are raised if the result is `None`):

```
    if default is None:
        default = datetime.datetime.now().replace(hour=0, minute=0,
                                                  second=0, microsecond=0)

    res, skipped_tokens = self._parse(timestr, **kwargs)

    if res is None:
        raise ParserError("Unknown string format: %s", timestr)

    if len(res) == 0:
        raise ParserError("String does not contain a date: %s", timestr)

    try:
        ret = self._build_naive(res, default)
    except ValueError as e:
        six.raise_from(ParserError(str(e) + ": %s", timestr), e)
```

The filling in happens in `_build_naive`.

So, I am not suggesting this is the best route to go. But you can monkey-patch `parser._parse` to raise an error if we don't find all of a day, month and year attributes on the result. To make this slightly safer, we can wrap our patching in a context manager:

```py
import contextlib
import dateutil.parser

@contextlib.contextmanager
def strict_parser():
    original_parse = dateutil.parser._parser.parser._parse
    def _parse_patch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return_value = original_parse(self, *args, **kwargs)
        parsed_result = return_value[0]
        for attr in "year", "month", "day":
            if not getattr(parsed_result, attr, None):
                raise dateutil.parser.ParserError(
                    f"Require a full year, month, and day, did not find a {attr}"
                )
        return return_value
    dateutil.parser._parser.parser._parse = _parse_patch # do the monkey patch
    try:
        yield
    finally:
        dateutil.parser._parser.parser._parse = original_parse
```

So, here is how this would work:

```
In [1]: import contextlib
   ...: import dateutil.parser
   ...:
   ...: @contextlib.contextmanager
   ...: def strict_parser():
   ...:     original_parse = dateutil.parser._parser.parser._parse
   ...:     def _parse_patch(self, *args, **kwargs):
   ...:         return_value = original_parse(self, *args, **kwargs)
   ...:         parsed_result = return_value[0]
   ...:         for attr in "year", "month", "day":
   ...:             if not getattr(parsed_result, attr, None):
   ...:                 raise dateutil.parser.ParserError(
   ...:                     f"Require a full year, month, and day, did not find a {attr}"
   ...:                 )
   ...:         return return_value
   ...:     dateutil.parser._parser.parser._parse = _parse_patch # do the monkey patch
   ...:     try:
   ...:         yield
   ...:     finally:
   ...:         dateutil.parser._parser.parser._parse = original_parse
   ...:

In [2]: dateutil.__version__
Out[2]: '2.8.2'

In [3]: dateutil.parser.parse("12:00-16:00")
Out[3]: datetime.datetime(2023, 8, 22, 12, 0, tzinfo=tzoffset(None, -57600))

In [4]: with strict_parser():
   ...:     print(dateutil.parser.parse("12:00-16:00"))
   ...:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ParserError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[4], line 2
      1 with strict_parser():
----> 2     print(dateutil.parser.parse("12:00-16:00"))

File ~/miniconda3/envs/py311/lib/python3.11/site-packages/dateutil/parser/_parser.py:1368, in parse(timestr, parserinfo, **kwargs)
   1366     return parser(parserinfo).parse(timestr, **kwargs)
   1367 else:
-> 1368     return DEFAULTPARSER.parse(timestr, **kwargs)

File ~/miniconda3/envs/py311/lib/python3.11/site-packages/dateutil/parser/_parser.py:640, in parser.parse(self, timestr, default, ignoretz, tzinfos, **kwargs)
    636 if default is None:
    637     default = datetime.datetime.now().replace(hour=0, minute=0,
    638                                               second=0, microsecond=0)
--> 640 res, skipped_tokens = self._parse(timestr, **kwargs)
    642 if res is None:
    643     raise ParserError("Unknown string format: %s", timestr)

Cell In[1], line 12, in strict_parser.<locals>._parse_patch(self, *args, **kwargs)
     10 for attr in "year", "month", "day":
     11     if not getattr(parsed_result, attr, None):
---> 12         raise dateutil.parser.ParserError(
     13             f"Require a full year, month, and day, did not find a {attr}"
     14         )
     15 return return_value

ParserError: Require a full year, month, and day, did not find a year

In [5]: with strict_parser():
   ...:     print(dateutil.parser.parse("10/08/1988"))
   ...:
1988-10-08 00:00:00

In [6]: dateutil.parser.parse("12:00-16:00")
Out[6]: datetime.datetime(2023, 8, 22, 12, 0, tzinfo=tzoffset(None, -57600))
```

Again, monkey-patching is always  hack. But it is relatively easy to do. of course, you take on the responsibility now of maintaining this patch because it uses internal, implementation details.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed feedback. I don't think my employer will want us to take on that maintenance load, but it's good to know.